# How to concatenate, element-wise, two document corpora in R using tm

Tags: r, nlp, tm

Start with two corpora of documents, each with the same number of documents:

```
library(tm)
c1 <- Corpus(VectorSource(c("document 1 corpus 1 text", "document 2 corpus 1 text")))
c2 <- Corpus(VectorSource(c("document 1 corpus 2 text", "document 2 corpus 2 text")))
```

I want a single corpus of the same number of documents with the terms combined element-wise to form a single document, the equivalent of:

```
c3 <- Corpus(VectorSource(c("document 1 corpus 1 text document 1 corpus 2 text", 
                            "document 2 corpus 1 text document 2 corpus 2 text"))
```

Searching has turned up the `tm_combine` function, but that combines the documents from different corpora into a single corpus with twice the (or, the sum of the individual) number of documents.

Comment: @Jota That looks like a good answer

Comment: @Jota yes! That is perfect. I did not know about the `content` function. Upvoted comment, but put as an answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop through each corpus and paste corresponding entries together.  Then, convert back into a corpus:

```
Corpus(VectorSource(
  mapply(function(x, y) paste(content(x), content(y)), c1, c2)
))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
c4 <-
  Corpus(VectorSource(c(  
  paste(data.frame(text=unlist(sapply(c1, `[`, "content")), stringsAsFactors=F)$text[1],
        data.frame(text=unlist(sapply(c1, `[`, "content")), stringsAsFactors=F)$text[2]),
  paste(data.frame(text=unlist(sapply(c2, `[`, "content")), stringsAsFactors=F)$text[1],
        data.frame(text=unlist(sapply(c2, `[`, "content")), stringsAsFactors=F)$text[2]))))
```

Comment: Upvoted, but will accept @Jota's for conciseness. Thanks.